# HorizontalScrollView inside Horizontal RecylerView not scrolling

Tags: android, nested, android-recyclerview, scrollview

i know it is not advised to add a scroll able view inside another scroll able view, but this requirement can not be changed.
so i have a regular RecylerView with a LinearLayoutManager orientation Horizontal.

```
 LinearLayoutManager manager2 = new LinearLayoutManager(context,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
 rec_products.setLayoutManager(manager2);
```

it has a custom view inside which is inflated in adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/productblue"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">



    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/icon_abc"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/products_item_options"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/product_layout_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/product_layout_icon_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_cart_new"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Add"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/products_item_options"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/product_layout_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/product_layout_icon_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_cart_new"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Color Option"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/products_item_options"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/product_layout_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/product_layout_icon_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_emailquotegray"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Email Quote"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/products_item_options"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/product_layout_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/product_layout_icon_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_brochureemailgray"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Email Brochure"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                style="@style/products_item_options"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/product_layout_icon_size"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/product_layout_icon_size"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/icon_brochureemailgray"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Check Stock"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

nothing special done in adapter, just regular viewholder inflation and binding.
the horizontal scroll view is not scrolling. what can i do to fix this?

Comment: Fix the width of horizontal scroll view.

Comment: @Ramit still doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

When you use a RecyclerView, you need to specify a LayoutManager that is responsible for laying out each item in the view. The LinearLayoutManager allows you to specify an orientation, just like a normal LinearLayout would.

To create a horizontal list with RecyclerView, you might do something like this:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
= new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

RecyclerView myList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
myList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
```

Comment: No need to specify Horizontal Scroll VIew for recycler View.

Comment: Initialise a recycler VIew and Add my code i mentioned

Comment: I mean create a recycler view and initalise in ur Main Activity

Comment: i think you didn't understood the question. i need an horizontal scroll view in each of my items, which i am showing in a recylerview which is also horizontally scroll able. i have done all of that already, the only problem left is that horizontalscrollview is not scrolling when i run the app, recylerview does scroll. i want both of them to scroll.

Comment: U will get a  better idea with this article for horizontal scroll view http://abhiandroid.com/ui/scrollview

Comment: your answers are not at all relevant with my question. have you understand the problem yet?